# how to create expandable sunburst with d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

jsfiddle.net/spacehaz/jpzaj92o/31

I want to create sunburst and give it an event listener with a callback, that will expand it, not zoom! so the idea is to expand all deeper levels to 100% (and to hide all other branches starting from the root) ! I found the solution to do a zoom, but that is not a solution, i need to expand it, not to zoom! here is the code I have right now:

```
var app = {}

function stash (d) {
  d.x0 = d.x
  d.dx0 = d.dx
}



function getSvg (width, height, margin) {
  return d3.select('#sunburst').append('svg')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height)
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + width / 2 + ',' + height / 2 + ')')
}


function prepareArcForSunburst (component) {
    var arc = d3
      .svg
      .arc()
      .startAngle(function (d) {
        return Math.max(0, Math.min(2 * Math.PI, component.x(d.x)))
      })
      .endAngle(function (d) {
        return Math.max(0, Math.min(2 * Math.PI, component.x(d.x + d.dx)))
      })
      .innerRadius(function (d) {
        return Math.max(0, component.y(d.y))
      })
      .outerRadius(function (d) {
        return Math.max(0, component.y(d.y + d.dy))
      })

    return arc
  }

  function preparePartitionOptionsForSunburst () {
    var partition = d3
      .layout
      .partition()
      .sort(null)
      .value(function (d) {
        return 1
      })

    return partition
  }

  function compileDataForSunburst (component, partition, data) {
    var dataCompiled = component
      .svg
      .datum(data)
      .selectAll('path')
      .data(partition.nodes)
    return dataCompiled
  }


  function drawChart (data) {
    var color = d3.scale.category20c();
    this.initiallyDrawed = true
    var margin = { left: 20 }
    var component = app
    component.width = 300
    component.height = component.width
    component.data = data
    component.radius = Math.min(component.width, component.height) / 2
    component.x = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([0, 2 * Math.PI])

    component.y = d3.scale.sqrt()
        .range([0, component.radius])

    component.svg = getSvg(component.width, component.height, margin)

    component.partition = preparePartitionOptionsForSunburst()

    // данные по углам и радиусам каждой ячейки
    component.arc = prepareArcForSunburst(component)
    var dataCompiled = compileDataForSunburst(component, component.partition, data)
    var arcTweenZoom = function (d) {
      var component = app
      var xd = d3.interpolate(component.x.domain(), [d.x, d.x + d.dx])
      var yd = d3.interpolate(component.y.domain(), [d.y, 1])
      var yr = d3.interpolate(component.y.range(), [d.y ? 20 : 0, component.radius])
      return function (d, i) {
        return i ? function (t) {
          return component.arc(d)
        } : function (t) {
          component.x.domain(xd(t))
          component.y.domain(yd(t)).range(yr(t))
          return component.arc(d)
        }
      }
    }
    var magnify = function (d) {
      var component = app
      component.path
        .transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .attrTween('d', arcTweenZoom(d))
    }
    component.path = dataCompiled
      .enter()
      .append('path')
      .attr('d', component.arc)
      .style('stroke', '#fff')
      .on('click', magnify)
      .style('fill', function (d) {
        return color((d.children ? d : d.parent).name);
      })
      .style('fill-rule', 'evenodd')
      .each(stash)

    d3.select(self.frameElement).style('height', component.height + 'px')
  }
```

and here are screen shots. Here is the initial state with hovered item i would like to expand:
[image]

and here is the state I would like to reach with transition(!!) 
[image]

Comment: You're saying you want to show more data, not just get a closer view of current data?

Comment: @sova no, the idea is that i want to expand selected item on sunburst and all the lower levels to 100% and hide other branches at all!

Comment: could you adda a link to a jsfiddle ?

Comment: @sova please check the images above

Comment: @spacehaz you need to show us what you've coded so far and not just provide images.

Comment: @sova https://jsfiddle.net/spacehaz/jpzaj92o/31/

Comment: @RobertLongson jsfiddle.net/spacehaz/jpzaj92o/31

Comment: Put the code in the question itself please. A fiddle should be an extra, not a necessity.

Comment: Could you please describe in other words what the animation you wish to achieve would look like?  Currently it does an arc-zoom.  You just want it to "expand" ... Are there any examples somewhere of this effect in action?

Comment: @sova no, i cant find examples. I want to happen animation in this way: segment I clicked on should expand to the whole arc, all other segments on the same level should collapse smoothly.the same will happen to it's parent segments. I tried to show it on pictures above. Right now the animation is not about expansion, it is about zoom first of all. But I do not need zoom, I need to expand the segment I clicked on and it's parents. All child segments of the clicked segment should also expand to the whole arc (on the picture above you can see how it should look like)